# Elasticsearch index of 1TB of data and growing

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-performance

I would like to know what is the best thing to do to move forward with a 1TB elasticsearch index (The recommendation from elasticsearch is 50 GB). Should we reindex this information into different indexes?

How should we do the migration taking into account that we cannot stop the service that reads and writes from the elasticsearch?

Right now we don't have a bad performance but we don't know how much time we will be able to keep the current performance.

thanks for your help

Comment: It's not an easy question to answer because it heavily depends on your use cases and how you interact with your index. First off, how many shards does your index have? (the 50GB advice is per shard, not per index) and how much RAM, resp. heap, do each of your nodes have? Can you jot down some numbers to give us an idea of your topology?